# Serialization Custom DataType

Tags: xml, serialization, xsd

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ObjectEnvelopeType objectenvelopetype = new ObjectEnvelopeType();
        objectenvelopetype.DocumentReference.DocumentID = 345;

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObjectEnvelopeType));
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("Object.xml", FileMode.Create);
        serializer.Serialize(fs, objectenvelopetype);
        fs.Close();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
public partial class ObjectEnvelopeType
{
 private ReferenceType documentReferenceField;
 public ReferenceType DocumentReference{get{return this.documentReferenceField;}set{documentReferenceField = value;}}
}

public partial class ReferenceType
{
    private IdentifierType documentIDField;
    public IdentifierType DocumentID{get{return documentIDField;}set{documentIDField = value;}} 
}
public partial class DocumentReferenceType
{
    private IdentifierType idField;
    public IdentifierType ID{get{return this.idField;}set{this.idField = value;}}
}
public partial class IdentifierType 
{
    private string identificationSchemeIDField;
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType = "normalizedString")]
    public string identificationSchemeID{get{return this.identificationSchemeIDField;}set{this.identificationSchemeIDField = value;}} 
}
```

I Convert XSD to c# Class now when i create object of class and assign a value am getting error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'Frameworkgo.Envelope.IdentifierType

am doing serialization kindly help me on that

THANKYOU

Comment: it is very hard to comment on this without a sample xml fragment to try it against... but it *sounds* like the XML has `<DocumentID>42</DocumentID>` or similar, but your definition expects `<DocumentID identificationSchemeID="abc"/>` ? example data would really help here...

Answer (score 0):

Running and test 100%.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ObjectEnvelopeType objectenvelopetype = new ObjectEnvelopeType();
            objectenvelopetype.DocumentReference = new ReferenceType();
            objectenvelopetype.DocumentReference.DocumentID = 345;

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObjectEnvelopeType));
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("Object.xml", FileMode.Create);
            serializer.Serialize(fs, objectenvelopetype);
            fs.Close();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public partial class ObjectEnvelopeType
    {
        private ReferenceType documentReferenceField;
        public ReferenceType DocumentReference { get { return this.documentReferenceField; } set { documentReferenceField = value; } }
    }

    public partial class ReferenceType
    {
        private int documentIDField;
        public int DocumentID { get { return documentIDField; } set { documentIDField = value; } }
    }
    public partial class DocumentReferenceType
    {
        private IdentifierType idField;
        public IdentifierType ID { get { return this.idField; } set { this.idField = value; } }
    }
    public partial class IdentifierType
    {
        private string identificationSchemeIDField;
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType = "normalizedString")]
        public string identificationSchemeID { get { return this.identificationSchemeIDField; } set { this.identificationSchemeIDField = value; } }
    }
}
```